# how to solve Twig environment not injecting into shopware 6.5.4.0 when trying to use twig function

Tags: symfony, twig, shopware6

I am working on a custom plugin that accepts data from an api.

I am trying to use a twig function to get the data as below

twig function class:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Nst\Twig;

use Nst\Service\StoryblokService;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class StoryblokTwigExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function __construct(private StoryblokService $storyblokService)
    {
  
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_story', [$this, 'getStory']),
        ];
    }

    public function getStory(string $slug): array
    {
        return $this->storyblokService->getStory($slug);
    }
}
```

also in my services:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services">
    <services>
        <service id="Nst\Service\StoryblokService" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="Storyblok\Client"/>
        </service>
        
        <service id="Storyblok\Client" class="Storyblok\Client">
            <argument>%env(dumpcode)%</argument>
        </service>

        <service id="Nst\Storefront\Controller\CodesController" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="twig"/>
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

and then in my controller where I am rendering page, I try to inject in to my construct for use.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Nst\Storefront\Controller;

use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Twig\Environment;

/**
 * @Route(defaults={"_routeScope"={"storefront"}})
 */
class CodesController extends StorefrontController
{    


    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }
    
    public function setTwig(Environment $twig): void
{
    $this->twig = $twig;
    error_log('Twig has been set.'); // or use your preferred logging method
}

    /**
    * @Route("/mystore", name="frontend.example.example", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"_routeScope"={"storefront"}})
    */
    public function showPage(): Response
    {
        if (!$this->twig) {
            error_log('Twig is not set.');
        }
        
        return $this->renderStorefront('@Nst/storefront/page/example.html.twig', [
            'example' => 'Hello world'
        ]);
    }
}
```

a copy of my twig page, where I need this twig function to display the data consumed from the api.

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}

{% block base_content %}
    <h1>Our example controller!</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% set story = get_story('ola-landing-page') %}

{% if story %}
    {# Display your story content here #}
    {{ story.content.title }}
    {# Add more fields as required from the story #}
{% endif %}
```

but I keep getting

```
hp.CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Too few arguments to function Nst\Storefront\Controller\CodesController::__construct(), 0 passed in 

Uncaught PHP Exception Shopware\Storefront\Controller\Exception\StorefrontException: "Class Nst\Storefront\Controller\CodesController does not have twig injected. Add to your service definition a method call to setTwig with the twig instance" at
```

I don't know what to do, been on it for a very long period please help

Comment: in my own context how do I use this? this is the first time Im messing with twig functions @DarkBee

Comment: what I do understand is that I would not need to inject in using the construct anymore right? @DarkBee

Comment: That is correct yes, but I'm wondering if you even need that (extra) service then. Anyway, twig itself doesn't know about any services and can't pass arguments required, cause it doesn't have the required variables set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [auto-inject](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#environment-aware-filters) the twig environment by adding the `needs_environment` option and setting it to true, then the correct instance will be passed to your `TwigFunction` automatically

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Nst\Twig;

use Nst\Service\StoryblokService;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class StoryblokTwigExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function __construct(private StoryblokService $storyblokService)
    {
  
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_story', [$this, 'getStory'], [ 'needs_environment' => true),
        ];
    }

    public function getStory(\Twig\Environment $twig, string $slug): array
    {
        /*
            Now you can use $twig to render something
            or you could even pass it to the service if needed/wanted
            ....
            return $twig->render(....);
            $this->storyblockService->setTwig($twig);
            ...
        */   
        return $this->storyblokService->getStory($slug);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You extend shopwares `StorefrontController` and in that controller the `setTwig()` function is already defined. So it is best to not override that function in your own controller, as you don't want to change the way that twig is injected into the controller.

Shopware uses [setter injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection) to inject the twig template into the storefront controllers, but you try to inject it over the [constructor](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#constructor-injection).

I would suggest to remove the override of the `setTwig` function in your controller and remove the constructor as well, as you don't need it if you inject the twig environment over a setter (of course you can add it back if you have more dependencies in your controller that you want to inject there).

Then add a call to the setTwig function in services.xml:

```xml
        <service id="Nst\Storefront\Controller\CodesController" public="true">
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
                <call method="setTwig">
                <argument type="service" id="twig"/>
            </call>
        </service>
```

From an architectural point of view i would suggest that you don't just load the actual content during the twig rendering over a custom twig function, but do exactly that in the controller and then render the twig template with that variable already set.

If you want to stick with your twig function, i guess you need to configure that class as well in the services.xml file, so that twig actually picks it up: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-twig-function

Comment: yes that's correct it has to be configured In the services